# How to verify Do Not Track (DNT) in HTTP request headers?

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, request-headers

I am setting [DNT](http://www.w3.org/TR/tracking-dnt/#dnt-header-field) value in HTTP request header by doing this:

```
request.setRequestHeader("DNT","1");
```

and I can see this in dev tools network tab as well
[image]

but is there any other way to verify this on UI or console logs which will demonstrate how and which specific sources (like scripts) of websites were not allowed to track the user.

Answer (score 2):

"DNT" is fully advisory. The browser does nothing besides sending it; it's up to the servers to process it.

Comment: so request headhers are the only way to verify from client side ?